# ionic3 multiple swiper sliders on samepage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 while placing 3 swiper sliders on same page i am unable to control their behavior separately i am bit new for angular js as well ts and ionic

here is code

```
<ion-slides style="height: 30%;" pager>
  <ion-slide style="background-color: green" *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <img [src]="post.image" />
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>


<ion-slides style="height: 30%;" pager>
  <ion-slide style="background-color: green" *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <img [src]="post.image" />
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

ts is

```
 @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  goToSlide() {
    this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);

  }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.slides.freeMode = true;
    this.slides .slidesPerView=3,
    this.slides.spaceBetween=5;
    //this.slides.loop=true;
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `ViewChild`, you can use `ViewChildren` to get all the instances of the slider in that page ([Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)). Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1eFQjY0v9TxFXS6ga7e)**. The end result would be something like this:

[image: Slider demo]

Like you can see in the plunker, we get all the instances of the slider, and then we just get the target instance by using its index:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChildren(Slides) slides: QueryList<Slides>;

  constructor() {}

  public move(index: number): void {
    this.slides.toArray()[index].slideNext(500);
  }      

}
```

An then in the view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic Demo</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-slides style="height: 75px" pager>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 1</h1></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 2</h1></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 3</h1></ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

  <ion-slides style="height: 75px" pager>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 1</h1></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 2</h1></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 3</h1></ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

  <ion-slides style="height: 75px" pager>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 1</h1></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 2</h1></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><h1>Slide 3</h1></ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button (click)="move(0)" ion-button text-only>Move First</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button (click)="move(1)" ion-button text-only>Move Second</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button (click)="move(2)" ion-button text-only>Move Third</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank You Sir U really saved my day

Comment: sir one extra question i want to use socketcluster or socket.io with ionic3 but unable to find any refrence i have working app with cordova.  just want to connect to that socket on ionic3 and display results